# Which preposition should follow "facilitated" (by or with)?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, by-with

Which preposition is correct to use with *facilitated*?

- This product is facilitated **with** three powerful tools to help you in testing tasks.

or

- This product is facilitated **by** three powerful tools to help you in testing tasks.

Comment: The idiomatic use is almost always "facilitated by," but you'll have to fill in the ellipsis (...) before anyone can be sure.

Comment: @deadrat thanks, I googled facilitated with and most of the websites using it for describing accommodation facilities. I edited my question as you suggested too.

Comment: "Facilitate" means to make some action or process easier.  But you've got a thing ("this product"), so something's wrong.  Either you mean it's something you do with the product (install? use?) or you need another verb (accompanied?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Deadrat that a process or action may be facilitated. That is, they may be helped. I also agree that a product cannot be facilitated. "Facilitated" is an ill-defined and pretentious word and probably should not be used here at all. The word you seek is "complemented". "The product is complemented by three tools". Or perhaps "the product contains three tools". Or "the product features three tools".

Comment: Or augmented. Or enhanced.